# Web3j java function call returns empty list on solidity contract

Tags: java, blockchain, ethereum, web3-java

I'm trying to call the function `getPrice` from this solidity contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract DataExchangeOfferContract {    
    uint price;

    constructor(uint _price) public {
        price = _price;
    }

    function getPrice() public constant returns (uint) {
        return price;
    }
}
```

I'm running a private blockchain client in debug mode using `geth`, and I deployed a contract with a value. Here is how I try to call the function of the only contract deployed:

```
EthBlock.Block block = web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, true).send().getBlock();
Transaction transaction = web3j.ethGetTransactionByBlockHashAndIndex(block.getHash(), BigInteger.ZERO).send().getTransaction().get();
String hash = transaction.getHash();

Function function = new Function(DataExchangeOfferContract.FUNC_GETPRICE, Collections.emptyList(), Collections.singletonList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
String functionEncoder = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);

Transaction transaction = Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(address, functionEncoder, null);
EthCall response = web3j.ethCall(transaction, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send();
List<Type> types = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(response.getValue(), function.getOutputParameters());
BigInteger price = (BigInteger) types.get(0).getValue();
```

Here `types` has 0 elements. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The missing thing is that the contract address is not the transaction hash.
The contract address is retrieved like this:

```
EthGetTransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(hash).send();
String address = transactionReceipt.getTransactionReceipt().get().getContractAddress();
```

Then as pointed out in the responses, the call can be called using the contract wrapper, or using the previously described approach, **passing the contract address and not the transaction hash as parameter**.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to just get the price from the latest block, you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. Assuming `DataExchangeOfferContract` is your generated stub (your Solidity code just says `Contract`), you already have a `getPrice` method defined. To use it, your code should look something like this:

```
Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());

TransactionManager manager = new ReadonlyTransactionManager(web3j, "YOUR_ADDRESS");
DataExchangeOfferContract contract = DataExchangeOfferContract.load("CONTRACT_ADDRESS", web3j, 
                                                                    manager, Contract.GAS_PRICE,
                                                                    Contract.GAS_LIMIT);
RemoteCall<BigInteger> remoteCall = contract.getPrice();
BigInteger price = remoteCall.send();
```

Comment: When I do it that way, I get `org.web3j.tx.exceptions.ContractCallException: Empty value (0x) returned from contract`